# Terraform - How to initialize set variable in tfvars

Tags: terraform

## Background

The Terraform document clearly states variable defined in the root module can be set in `tfvars` file.

[Type Constraints](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#type-constraints)

> The type constructors allow you to specify complex types such as collections:
>
> - set(`<TYPE>`)

[Assigning Values to Root Module Variables](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#assigning-values-to-root-module-variables)

> When variables are declared in the root module of your configuration, **they can be set** in a number of ways:
>
> - In variable definitions (.tfvars) files, either specified on the command line or automatically loaded.

An input variable of type `set` can be defined in a root module.

variables.tf

```
variable "roles" {
  description = "IAM roles to grant to the service account"
  type    = set(string)
}
```

## Question

Please advise how to initialize the `set` variable in tfvars? Using function is not allowed, and as far as I looked around, it looks there is no example in the Terraform documentations. Or if setting `set` is not supported, is it clearly documented?

terraform.tfvars

```
roles = toset([
  "roles/cloudsql.client",
  "roles/bigquery.dataEditor",
  "roles/storage.admin",
  "roles/pubsub.edito",
  "roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor",
  "roles/artifactregistry.reader"
])
```

```
Error: Function calls not allowed
│ 
│   on sa.auto.tfvars line 1:
│    1: roles = toset([
│    2:   "roles/cloudsql.client",
│    3:   "roles/bigquery.dataEditor",
│    4:   "roles/storage.admin",
│    5:   "roles/pubsub.edito",
│    6:   "roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor",
│    7:   "roles/artifactregistry.reader"
│    8: ])
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just define it as:

```
roles = [
  "roles/cloudsql.client",
  "roles/bigquery.dataEditor",
  "roles/storage.admin",
  "roles/pubsub.edito",
  "roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor",
  "roles/artifactregistry.reader"
]
```

TF will automatically convert it to the correct type.